# Generate Some Secure PINs

Tags: code-golf, number, random

*Inspired by [this badly received migrated post](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/60525/generating-non-dictionary-numeric-passcodes).*

The head of security at your company is concerned about your PIN generating system after it gave him `12345`. He also didn't really appreciate the Spaceballs joke you made at his expense, so you've been delegated to re-write the PIN generator. Since it has to fit on some special hardware, you have to make it as small as possible.

## Your Task

- You take two inputs - # of PINs, and PIN size in digits.
- Generate the specified number of PINs of the specified size **randomly** and print it out.
- All valid PIN's of the size must be possible to be printed out, even if they aren't uniformly probable.
- However, there are some restrictions on the PINs - here are the invalid ones:

  1. If all the pairs are the same digit: `114422` (Note: this will obviously include all same digit PINs).
  2. Increasingly linear PINs (mod 10): `246802`.
  3. All groups of 3 are physical lines on the keypad of `1 2 3;4 5 6;7 8 9;bksp 0 enter;`: `147369`.
  4. The PIN can be entirely split up into groups from rule 1 and rule 3.

- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code in **bytes** wins!

Comment: Does rule one also include a single double pair (like `55123`)?

Comment: @minxomat good point, ammending the rules to include both groups. That one will since the second half is `123`, but `55432` would be fine.

Comment: Does rule 3 include diagonals?

Comment: The irony is that this definition of a so called "secure" pin only reduces the number of pins attackers might have to brute force!

Comment: @MartinBüttner no.

Comment: What's the shortest length for rule 2?

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, 120 bytes

```
Arz7VGJ1WJK%"%0*d",HO-^TH1=J|q1l{m%-F_vMcd1T.:K2u|GHmu|GHm?qlk2:k"(.)\\1"0?qlk3}k+++=bcS"123456789"3_Mb.Tb_M.TbZdZ./K0)K
```

Figured I should add a real implementation then. Generates random numbers until one is found that meets all requirements. Can probably be improved a lot!

[Online version](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=Arz7VGJ1WJK%25%22%250%2ad%22%2CHO-%5ETH1%3DJ%7Cq1l%7Bm%25-F_vMcd1T.%3AK2u%7CGHmu%7CGHm%3Fqlk2%3Ak%22%28.%29%5C%5C1%220%3Fqlk3%7Dk%2B%2B%2B%3DbcS%22123456789%223_Mb.Tb_M.TbZdZ.%2FK0%29K&input=10+7&debug=0)

Comment: I have changed the rules to include the requirement that PINs must be random, and all PINs must be possible.

Comment: I thought you might :)

Answer (score 0):

## Perl 5, 244

Starts with generating random numbers for the given size.
And only prints those that don't meet the restrictions.

Finding a solution for the keypad lines (without hardcoding combinations) was kinda fun.

```
($k,$l)=@ARGV;$m=10**$l-1;while($n<$k){$_=sprintf("%0".$l."d",int(rand($m)));@N=split//,$_;pop@N;$i=$d=0;while(++$i<@N&&$d<1){$d=$N[$i-1]<=>$N[$i]}$b=$_;$b=~s|\d|@A=split//,$';2*$A[0]-$&-$A[1]==0|eg;if((!m/(\d)\1/)&$b>0&$d>=0){$n++;print$_.$/}}
```

## Test

```
$ perl gen_pins.pl 10 5
98121
15931
69042
93730
83458
25312
24601
49468
49490
67012
```